# How to redirect static files requests to https in Nginx?

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I have two versions of site with urls: `http://example.com` and `https://example.com`.

I want to redirect all requests to static content (files that is ended with `.html`, `.htm`, `.js`) to https version of my site.

So, I created the rule:

```
location ~ "\.(htm|html|js|css|svg|png)$" {
        return 307 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

With this rule browser changes address of my site to `https://example.com`.

But I don't want to change address, I want that all requests to static files but not to `index.html` (main html of my site) will be redirected to https version.

How can I add something like `AND NOT index.html` to regex `~ "\.(htm|html|js|css|svg|png)$"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
root /path/to/root;

location = /index.html {
}

location ~ "\.(htm|html|js|css|svg|png)$" {
    return 307 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The `location =` block has highest precedence (the order is not important).

Because of an explicit or implicit `index index.html` statement, the URI `/` causes `nginx` to look for `/index.html`. The empty location block will cause the static file to be served, and the `return 307` avoided.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.